# Why we often refer John Kennedy as JFK, but seldom refer Richard Nixon as RMN?

Tags: abbreviations, names

Let's make this question more general. Why people refer some specific person as the abbreviation of his/her **given name + middle name + surname** (e.g. JFK, LBJ) rather than full spelled **given name + surname**?

And why people refer Thomas Edward Lawrence as T. E. Lawrence rather than TEL or Thomas Lawrence?

Comment: Erm... because saying (and writing) JFK is faster than saying John Fitzgerald Kennedy?

Comment: I don't think there's any rhyme or reason to this. At the beginning of notoriety, journalists may pick one or another nickname just for fun and it sticks or doesn't, purely out of repeating enough by others. There may be some poetic assonance or it just stands out nicely  or differentiates from others. But there's no good reason why usually.

Comment: [Can't edit old comment] Authors' first names tend to be initials for the sake of brevity, it takes up less room on the book cover, e.g. J.K Rowling. But in the case of William Shakespeare, his name is never clipped. I suppose this stems back to  the time when schools had so many students crammed in a single classroom, teachers just read out students' last names (surnames). I don't think this feature is peculiar to the English language, I think it's common in other European authors/statesmen.

Comment: Kennedy was known almost universally as John F Kennedy even before he was elected. Also President Roosevelt was known as Franklin D, President Johnson was called Lyndon B and the second President Bush is George W. This seems to be moderately common in American public life, presumably it starts when there is someone else with whom they can confused earlier in their life. The shortening of the name to three initials happens after they become famous. For whatever reason Tricky Dicky Nixon was never widely known as Richard M Nixon so his widely known name could not be turned into three letters.

Comment: It's often just a matter of what rolls off the tongue.  FDR, JFK, and LBJ all have a musical quality to them.  RMN just doesn't - we all call him 'Nixon'.  Clinton, Bush, and Obama will never be WJC, GWB, or BHO.  Trump, on the other hand, might be DJT.  I had a similar question I posed once to a sports announcer.  Mine was in relation to the names of certain professional sports events, some of which the sponsor's name easily attaches, and other not.  He gave the example of the (cycling race) "The Amgen Tour of California".  Other races have a  sponsor, but that just rolls off the tongue well.

Answer (score 2):

Lawrence preferred his initials to his names, so, [T. E. Lawrence](https://www.britannica.com/biography/T-E-Lawrence).

As to US presidents, I think one has to go back to Theodore Roosevelt. He was frequently referred to as "T.R.". That would have little impact on this matter but that T.R.'s cousin, Franklin, came along in public service at the end of Theodore's life. FDR was a convenient way to distinguish Franklin from T.R. and other Roosevelts. It was good for newspapers to have a short form of Roosevelt, also.
(Harry) Truman was not likely to be confused with any other prominent American
 and rarely was referred to as HST.

(Dwight) Eisenhower also did not need to be distinguished from other Eisenhowers as a rule, and already had the moniker "Ike".

There were prominent Kennedys besides John F. so JFK was a good short form to identify the president. Same for Lyndon Johnson, LBJ was not ambiguous.

Nixon was not so common a name, and was only five letters. Ford was only four letters.

(Jimmy) Carter was occasionally JEC, but that never caught on.

(Ronald) Reagan was not easily confused with other Reagans.  RWR didn't seem to work.

Bush is just four letters. George H. W.Bush's son is often referred to as George W. to distinguish him from his father.

Obama is only five letters. WJC probably won't work for someone usually known as Bill Clinton.

Possibly the practice of "initializing" presidential names will go out of style as newspapers become less influential. The need to fit names in type set-ups was a significant factor in reaching for short forms.

Comment: Ike was often referred to as "DDE".

Comment: I will not dispute that, but, I lived through his entire presidency and do not recall it.

Comment: I lived through it too, and clearly recall it.

Comment: ......OK, I do not doubt you

Comment: The first entry in the Wikipedia article on [DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDE) is a Norwegian rock band.

Comment: @ab2 - Uh, Wikipedia didn't exist back when DDE was in office.

Comment: @Hot Licks Punch in FDR and you get a Wikipedia article on Franklin Delano Roosevelt.

Comment: @ab2 - That just proves the liberal bias of Wikipedia.